# What range is calculated in Excel when using VBA .Calculate?

Tags: vba, excel

If I use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate
```

Is every cell on Sheet1 calculated, or only cells in the UsedRange?

I'm writing a subroutine that recalculates a variable number of rows and I'm ultimately trying to determine if my calculation will be faster using:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("VariableNumberOfRows").Calculate
```

Or

```
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Calculate
```

There are other rows outside the variable number of rows (and obviously inside the UsedRange), but these do not contain formulas therefore doesn't matter if they're included in the calculation.

If there's a technical article on what .Calculate specifically calculates (which cells, types of formulas) that would helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: See here http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm for a bunch of useful information on calculation in Excel.

Comment: See also this blog post discussing Range.calculate and Range.CalculateRowMajorOrder http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the answer is no, it does not calculate cells outside the used range. There would be nothing there, so there is nothing to calculate. Excel tracks the cells used (it has to in order to report the `.UsedRange`).

Use `.UsedRange` if you want all cells on the sheet that contain formulas to be calculated, or specify a smaller range if you only want that range calculated.